# Qt-Creator fails to detect external changes

Tags: qt-creator

I was used to QT-Craetor detecting external changes (e.g. ching out a file from git). In this case it always came up with a message that the file changed outside of QT-Creator and if I would like to accept/reject changes.
Now I switched to Qt-Creator 4.1.0 under Ubuntu 16.04 and the behaviour is gone. Missing Plugin ? Service ?

Thanks in advance
O.

Comment: Check if for some reason `Tools > Options > Environment > System > When files are externally modified` changed away from `Always ask`

Comment: @E4z9 **Bingo**